# How to avoid white screen on loading on ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

While loading app white screen appears sometimes after splash screen loaded. I search for answers but can't get proper solutions. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you're talking about SplashScreen. Take a look here
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/cli/icon-splashscreen.html